# How to combine 3 SQL request into one and order it Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm creating filter for my Point model on Ruby on Rails app. App uses ActiveAdmin+Ransacker for filters. I wrote 3 methods to filter the Point:

```
    def self.filter_by_customer_bonus(bonus_id)
      Point.joins(:customer).where('customers.bonus_id = ?', bonus_id)
    end

    def self.filter_by_classificator_bonus(bonus_id)
      Point.joins(:setting).where('settings.bonus_id = ?', bonus_id)
    end

    def self.filter_by_bonus(bonus_id)
      Point.where(bonus_id: bonus_id)
    end
```

Everything works fine, but I need to merge the result of 3 methods to one array. When The Points.count (on production server for example) > ***1000000*** it works too slow, and I need to merge all of them to one method. The problem is that I need to order the final merged array this way:

Result array should start with result of first method here, the next adding the second method result, and then third the same way.

Is it possible to move this 3 sqls into 1 to make it work faster and order it as I write before?

For example my Points are [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

Result of first = [1,2,3]

Result of second = [2,3,4]

Result of third = [5,6,7]

After merge I should get [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] but it should be with the result of 1 method, not 3+merge. Hope you understand me :)

UPDATE:

The result of the first answer:

```
Point Load (8.0ms)  SELECT "points".* FROM "points" INNER JOIN "customers" ON "customers"."number" = "points"."customer_number" INNER JOIN "managers" ON "managers"."code" = "points"."tp" INNER JOIN "settings" ON "settings"."classificator_id" = "managers"."classificator_id" WHERE "points"."bonus_id" = $1 AND "customers"."bonus_id" = $2 AND "settings"."bonus_id" = $3  [["bonus_id", 2], ["bonus_id", 2], ["bonus_id", 2]]
```

It return an empty array.

Comment: try Point.joins(:customer).where('customers.bonus_id = ?', bonus_id).or(Point.joins(:setting).where('settings.bonus_id = ?', bonus_id)).or(Point.where(bonus_id: bonus_id))

Comment: You need to order over a million rows? What are you going to do with them?

Comment: @DavidAldridge its just a filter, im not sure that after filter i get more them 10000 points.

Answer (score 1):

You can union these using `or` ([documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-or)):

```
def self.filter_trifecta(bonus_id)
  (
    filter_by_customer_bonus(bonus_id)
  ).or(
   filter_by_classificator_bonus(bonus_id)
  ).or(
    filter_by_bonus(bonus_id)
  )
end
```

Note: you might have to hoist those joins up to the first condition — I'm not sure of `or` will handle those forks well as-is.

Answer (score 0):

Below gives you all the results in a single query. if you have indexes on the foreign keys used here it should be able to handle million records:

The one provided earlier does an AND on all 3 queries, thats why you had zero results, you need union, below should work. (Note: If you are using rails 5, there is active record syntax for union, which the first commenter provided.)

**Updated**:

```
 Point.from(
            "(#{Point.joins(:customer).where(customers: {bonus_id: bonus_id).to_sql} 
            UNION 
           #{Point.joins(:setting).where(settings: {bonus_id: bonus_id}).to_sql} 
            UNION 
           #{Point.where(bonus_id: bonus_id).to_sql})
           AS points")
```

Instead you can also use your 3 methods like below:

```
   Point.from("(#{Point.filter_by_customer_bonus(bonus_id).to_sql}
                UNION
               #{Point.filter_by_classificator_bonus(bonus_id).to_sql}
                UNION
               #{Point.filter_by_bonus(bonus_id).to_sql}
               ) as points")
```

Comment: It works, but it always return me an empty array. Check update pls